# Batch script (Windows) string substitution with a twist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know how to do a literal string substitution in a batch script.  However, I have a specific situation where I need to substitute the value of a numeric variable

This is the script:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A L=2
:L1
if %L% EQU 0 goto :EOF
set STRING="THIS IS # TEST"
SET NEW=%STRING:#=%%L%
echo %NEW%
set /A L=%L% - 1
goto L1
```

I *want it* to display this:

```
THIS IS 2 TEST
THIS IS 1 TEST
```

But it ends up diplaying this instead:

```
THIS IS  TEST2
THIS IS  TEST1
```

Any tips on how to get it to do what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your almost there, just change

```
SET NEW=%STRING:#=%%L%
```

to

```
SET NEW=%STRING:#=!L!%
```

Answer (score 7):

Even the solutions of aphoria and Bali C will work, it's better to use

```
set "NEW=!STRING:#=%L%!"
```

As then the replacement will be done in the delayed expansion phase and not in the percent expansion phase.

This will also work with exclamation marks and carets in `STRING`

```
@echo off

set L=2
set "String=This is # test!"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "NEW=!STRING:#=%L%!"
echo !NEW!
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `!L!` to use delayed expansion.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A L=2
:L1
IF !L! EQU 0 goto :EOF
SET STRING=THIS IS # TEST
SET NEW=%STRING:#=!L!%
ECHO %NEW%
SET /A L=!L! - 1
GOTO L1
```

Actually, you don't have to use `!L!` everywhere, just in the `SET NEW=%STRING:#!L!%` line. I used it everywhere for visual consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun.  Here is how to do it without delayed expansion. **`:)`**

Using the `call` command to double expand the variables. Use double percents `%%` around the variable to evaluate second. Single percents `%` around the variable to evaluate first.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions
set /A L=2

:L1
if %L% EQU 0 goto :EOF
set "STRING=THIS IS # TEST"
call set "NEW=%%STRING:#=%L%%%"
echo %NEW%
set /A L=%L% - 1
goto L1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the STRING as a "format string" placing the desired variables in the right places enclosed in exclamation marks. This way, no further replacement of the values is needed, just display the format string in the usual way:

```
rem Define the "format string" with Delayed Expansion disabled:
set STRING=THIS IS !L! TEST
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A L=2
:L1
if %L% EQU 0 goto :EOF
   echo %STRING%
   set /A L=L - 1
goto L1
```

Or, with no Delayed\Expansion:

```
set STRING=THIS IS %%L%% TEST
set /A L=2
:L1
if %L% EQU 0 goto :EOF
   call echo %STRING%
   set /A L=L - 1
goto L1
```

Antonio